# What to use when SQL SELECT query isn't flexible/powerful enough

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, scripting

I have a query I need to pull which feels like it's beyond what standard SQL is designed for. It might be technically possible, but I feel the resulting query would be very difficult to plan, write, understand and maintain.

I basically have 4 tables with data which needs to go into 1 table, and that 1 table can't handle **all** the data that might have been in the original 4. I'll need to choose what data to use based on a number of factors, including field values, if fields are blank, and if data is duplicated. I also need to split a particular field that contains semi-colon delimited data.

Due to all this, I'm thinking some sort of scripting language might be best. I'm wondering what tools are best suited to this sort of work.

I'm pulling from a Microsoft SQL Server database and have heard of, but not really worked with, T-SQL. Perhaps T-SQL contains enough extra features that such a query could be easily written in it?

I'm happy to put the time into learning the necessary tools and languages, I just don't know what sort of tool I'm actually needing, and that's where I'm looking for advice.

*I've detailed my specific situation below, if that assists in providing an answer.*

---

> I need to export information from a high school student information
>   system (SIS) for import to a co-curricular management system. The relevant tables and
>   columns from the SIS are:
>
> ```
> ┌──────────┬────────────────┬─────────────────┬───────────────┐
> │  student │    parent      │    address      │  student_addr │
> ├──────────┼────────────────┼─────────────────┼───────────────┤
> │ PK id    │ PK id          │ PK parent_id    │ PK student_id │
> │    name  │    mother_name │ PK addr_num     │ PK parent_id  │
> │    email │    father_name │    phone        │ PK addr_num   │
> │          │                │    email        │ PK addr_type  │
> │          │                │                 │               │
> └──────────┴────────────────┴─────────────────┴───────────────┘
> ```
>
> So you have one `student` record for each student. `parent` records
>   may account for one or two actual people (a mother and a father, or
>   just a single parent) depending on the family structure. The `parent`
>   record then has multiple `address` records, usually 3-4, and sometimes
>   each will contain the same data, sometimes it might be different.
>
> These `address`es (and therefore `parent`s) are then linked to
>   students through the `student_addr` table, with the `addr_type`
>   defining for what purpose that address should be used for that student
>   (e.g. mass correspondence, personal correspondence, automatic
>   notifications).
>
> The `address.email` field sometimes contains multiple semi-colon
>   separated emails. Due to the fact that `student`s can be linked to
>   multiple `parent`s with multiple `address`es, one student could be
>   linked to many `address.email` fields, which of course themselves
>   could contain multiple addresses.
>
> I need to select a maximum of two parent names, phones and emails for
>   the co-curricular system:
>
> ```
> ┌───────────────┐
> │ student_id    │
> │ student_name  │
> │ student_email │
> │ parent1_name  │
> │ parent1_phone │
> │ parent1_email │
> │ parent2_name  │
> │ parent2_phone │
> │ parent2_email │
> └───────────────┘
> ```
>
> I will determine which `phone` and `email` to draw from for each
>   student based on a number of factors, such as:
>
> - if emails are duplicate
> - `addr_type`
> - if a particular field is blank or not

Comment: Just showing us sample input and output data with no explanation would be more powerful than this lengthy question.

Comment: That output table design is "not normalized". What happens if the birth parents are divorced and there are 2 step-parents as well? or parents that are overseas with grandparents involved etc etc. The "simple table" may seem like a good idea to have, but it will limit flexibility.

Comment: @Used_By_Already , I totally agree, but both of these are commercial systems that store data in those specific formats :(

Answer (score 0):

You could use efficient scripting languages like Python or PowerShell. But if you are not familiar with them it will probably take you longer than with SSIS. It's packed with functions that seem to be handy in your case and will allow you to visualize the workflow your data needs to follow.

btw: There are many other ETL tools available for this, I prefer SSIS, but depending on your source systems you might like another tool better. So be sure to Google before you start downloading and installing.